# How to automatically append gtkwidget in new line when no horizontal space is available in gtkbox?

Tags: c++, c, gtk

Let's say I have the following code

```cpp
m_box=gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,4);
gtk_widget_set_halign (m_box, GTK_ALIGN_START);
gtk_widget_set_valign (m_box, GTK_ALIGN_START);
```

Now I am adding multiple widgets and running out of horizontal space. How can I make it responsive?

NOTE:- I am using gtk4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something a `GtkBox` can do. It's quite "dumb" in that it doesn't care about reflowing or anything like that. It does one thing and one thing only: putting child widgets next to each other in a specific orientation.

For your use case, you might be more interested in [`Gtk.FlowBox`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.FlowBox.html), which rearranges its children when it can't allocate enough space

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and this does work, but now I am facing another problem: I can't create children of different sizes within the flowbox. It is always changing the children's size in the same row to make them the same size as the other row child.

Comment: Why should ever GtkBox work like that at all? I think "dumb" is a rude word. The library provides you those things already, though.

Comment: @SaptakBhoumik: what you're asking for isn't provided by GTK currently. You might be interested in following this [libadwaita MR](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libadwaita/-/merge_requests/219) though that introduces `AdwWrapBox`. You could try to implement something similar yourself, or you could wait until it gets added libadwaita (and maybe GTK at some point)

Comment: @Michi: no, putting things in a single row or column is literally the only thing a GtkBox is supposed to do, and the [docs](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Box.html) even explicitly call that out. GTK4 also made the conscious design decision not to use inheritance when a subclass acts differently, so trying to subclass a GtkBox to do something differently is not what you should be doing anyway.

Comment: You are complaining yourself about GtkBox that "it doesn't care about reflowing", but then you are posting that the GtkFlowBox does the Job. Probably my opinion or even yours are not that important I guess.

Comment: I don't really see what's your problem tbh (and why you downvoted it too). I didn't "complain" that GtkBox doesn't care about reflowing, that's just a literal fact about GtkBox. GtkFlowBox _does_ support it, but it's not a GtkBox, nor does it derive from it.